# ANTLR4 mutually left-recursive error when parsing

Tags: java, recursion, antlr

I have this ANTLR 4 grammar:

```
constantFixedExpresion : term (('+'|'-') term)+;

term : factor (('*'|'//'|'REM')factor)+;

factor : ('+'|'-')*
           ( wholeNumberConstant
           | constantFixedExpresion
           | 'TOFIXED' (stringConstant | bitCodeConstant)      
           | identifier)
         ('FIT'constantFixedExpresion)*;
```

I get the following error:

> error(119): LanguageA.g4::: The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [constantFixedExpresion, factor, term]

I tried so many ways but can't fix it. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 36):

Antlr is a LL(*) parser, which is in many ways "better" than a [LL(k) parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser), but still has many of its disavantages. One of these being the fact it can't deal with left-recursion (in fact, the version 4 can deal with left-recursion within the same rule). What the error is saying is that you have a left-recursion of a grammar, a bane for the LL parsers.

This is caused by this construction in your grammar:

```
constantFixedExpression: term ...;
term: factor ...;
factor: ('+' | '-')* (constantFixedExpression | ...) ...;
```

Since the `*` operator means 0 or more, I can instantiate it with 0, so the parser will do this: "try `constantFixedExpression`, so it needs to try `term`, so it needs to try `factor`, so it needs to try `constantFixedEXpression`, so it [...]" and you've got yourself an infinite loop.

---

Fortunately, context-free formal grammars have an equivalent transformation for removing left-recursion! It can be expressed generically by:

```
A -> Aa | b
-- becomes --
A -> bR
R -> aR | ε
```

Or in Antlr notation:

```
A: Aa | b;
// becomes
A: bR;
R: (aR)?;
```

More information about this process can be found in automaton/grammars books or in the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion).

---

I'll leave correcting your grammar with the refactoration to remove left-recursion as your work. However, I want to touch in another point: Antlr 4 can do left-recursion! As I mentioned, the version 4 can deal with left-recursion **within the same rule**. There are ways to indicate precedence and associativity of operators other than directly in parsing, as you're doing, in Antlr4. Let's see how it works:

```
expr: NUMBER
      |<assoc=right> expr '^' expr
      | expr '*' expr
      | expr '/' expr
      | expr '+' expr
      | expr '-' expr;
```

This is an example of a basic calculator grammar. The operators at the top are those with highest precedence, and those at the bottom are of lower precedence. This means `2+2*3` will be parsed as `2+(2*3)` rather than `(2+2)*3`. The `<assoc=right>` construction means the operator in right-associative, so `1^2^3` will be parsed as `1^(2^3)` rather than `(1^2)^3`.

As you can see, it is much easier to specify operators with left-recursion, so Antlr 4 is of big help in these moments! I recommend re-writing your grammar to make use of this feature.

Comment: I needed expr as optional, so something like expr? '*' expr? . But this is giving me same error.

Comment: @Bond do you really need it? Is the string `*******` a valid expression?

Comment: I think you meant:
`R -> aR | ε`
The way you wrote it the sequence "bab" is valid in the right-recursion version but not in the left-recursion one.

Comment: I swear, for a moment I thought this was a @JonSkeet reply because it was so thorough and nicely broken down.