# How to fix mutual left recursion in ANTLR4

Tags: java, recursion, antlr, antlr4

I have two rules that are mutually left recursive:

```
frag : ID
   | NUMBER
   | TRUE
   | FALSE
   | expr
;

expr: frag (PLUS | MINUS) frag
   | LBR expr RBR
   | frag
;
```

And the issue is:
`The following sets of rules are mutually left-recursive [frag, expr]`

I'm new to ANTLR4 and am having difficulty removing this mutual left recursion.

I understand that left recursion can be removed such that:

```
A -> Aa | b
-- becomes --
A -> bR
R -> aR | ε
```

See [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26460013/antlr4-mutually-left-recursive-error-when-parsing)

How might I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indirect left recursion isn”t allowed, but direct left recursion is. This will work fine:

```
expr: expr (PLUS | MINUS) expr
   | LBR expr RBR
   | ID
   | NUMBER
   | TRUE
   | FALSE
;
```

And if you still want a separate `frag` rule, you can do this of course:

```
frag : ID
   | NUMBER
   | TRUE
   | FALSE
;

expr: expr (PLUS | MINUS) expr
   | LBR expr RBR
   | frag
;
```

Comment: As shown by Bart, indirect left recursion (ILR) can be "fixed" using unfolding ("inlining" the RHS of a rule into another `a : b c; b : d e f; => a : (d e f) c;`), followed by ungrouping (basically distribution `z : (a b) c => z : a c | b c`), and reordering the alts (`a : b | c => a : c | b`). If it involves only one rule, you only need apply ungrouping and reordering to that rule. You can choose any rule to unfold, but some rules make better choices. As yet, there is no tool that automatically detects and removes ILR, but it could be done automatically for these easy cases.